# I'll say at farewell or at last?

Tags: idioms, expressions, lyrics

Which of the following would be more comprehensible to say in English:

- At last I'll tell?
- At farewell I'll say?
- The Last word?

as the title in [song А напоследок я скажу](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KL0KNYT5MQU&feature=related) (words by Bella Akhmadulina, musics by Andrei Petrov from Eldar Ryazanov's movie ["Cruel Romance", 1984](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090368/)), sang by Ponomareva (in movie "performed"  by Larissa Guzeeva and Nikita Mihalkov)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps ***And finally, I’ll say…***?  Whatever one uses, to make sense in context of the song it has to be something that can be followed by *goodbye*, which eg *I’ll tell* doesn’t work for.  If you want something that’ll fit the scansion and meaning of the song better: ***And, as the end arrives, I’ll say…*** — although then it starts to sounds like it should be referring to *My way*.

Comment: I like "And Finally, I'll say..."

Comment: I thought that goodbye is said when people intend to meet again?

Comment: @vgv8: no, not necessarily.  *Goodbye* can be said whether or not you expect to meet again.